# Problem with notifications

Tags: bug, notifications, achievements-dialog

I've noticed that in recent days, I haven't been getting notifications for rep increases.  The achievements feed reflects the increased rep, but it doesn't turn green.  If I don't check it manually, I have no way of knowing that anything has happened.  Another user confirmed that he is having the same problem.  What's going on?